# List random posts on single page in the current category

Tags: get-posts

I would like to show 8 random posts on single page from same category.

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach ($categories as $category) :
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 8, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'category' => $category->term_id);
    var_dump($category->term_id);
    $rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) :
    ?>

    <li><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

..but if the post has 2 or more categories it lists 16/24/32 posts. I hope anyone can help to me. Thanks!

Comment: you're iterating over each category and fetching 8 posts for each, what results do you want if the post has more than a single category?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you use a `foreach` loop on post categories. You can display random posts from the first returned category by getting rid of the `foreach` loop and using `$categories[0]->term_id` as your `category` in query args.

You can also try to grab all the category IDs for all your categories and include them as comma separated list. This will return 8 random posts from all categories associated with your post. Read more in the 'Paramaters' section of [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function.